# Installing NativeScript Windows Setup windows 32 Bits

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

I'm trying to install NativeScript on windows 7 32 bits, so I followed this: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-win#nativescript-advanced-setup-windows

so steps 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6 work! but the setup 6 doesn't work, it shows this error:

Spanish
C:\Windows\system32>"%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager" "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2re
        pository"

```
Esta versión de C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk8u192-b12\bin\java.exe 
no es compatible con la versión de Windows que está ejecutando. Compruebe la información de sistema del equ
ipo para consultar si necesita una versión x86 (32 bits) o x64 (64 bits) del programa, y después póngase en contacto con el editor del software.

    C:\Windows\system32>
```

**English Version of Error:**

```
This version of C: \ Program Files \ AdoptOpenJDK \ jdk8u192-b12 \ bin \ java.exe
It is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running. Check the system information of the equ
ipo to check if you need an x86 (32 bit) or x64 (64 bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
```

what can I do???

Comment: It seems to me that the adoptopenjdk you have installed is the 64 bit version. Try to get the adoptopenjdk 32 bit applicable to your machine. https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html

Comment: ok.... do you know if nativescript is only to windows 64 bits??? or it can work on 32 bits?

Comment: I can' completely say offhand as I have configured NS for 64 bit systems. Never tried it on a 32 bit OS.